# How to fix "can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed" on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The error, 'cannot invoke 'button' command: application has been destroyed', and I do not understand why.

I have tried seperating the two root.mainloop()s in to two functions, however, this has not worked. This is for a game at school.

```
### PATHOGEN EVOLUTION ###

### IMPORT ###

import tkinter as tk #Imports the module, 'tkinter', as 'tk'
import random as r #Imports the module, 'random', as 'r'
import time as t #Imports the module, 'time', as 't'

### FUNCTION ###

def game ():
    global startButton
    global tuberculosisImage
    startButton.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
    imageLoad()

def imageLoad ():
    pathogen = tk.Button(root, image = tuberculosisImage)
    pathogen.pack()
    root.mainloop()



### CODE ###

global startButton
global tuberculosisImage

root = tk.Tk() #Creates a root window named 'root'
root.geometry("1020x720") #Sets the window size of the window, 'root',    to 1020 x 720
root.title("Pathogen Evolution") #Changes the title of the window, 'root', to 'Pathogen Evolution'
root.iconbitmap("favicon(1).ico") #Changes the icon of the window, 'root'

startButton = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", border = 2, command = game)
tuberculosisImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "pathogen1.gif")

startButton.pack()

root.mainloop() #Refreshes the window, 'root'
```

Comment: A call to `.mainloop()` will not finish until all windows are closed.  The call to `imageLoad()` inside `game()` will therefore not execute until the end of the program, at which point you can no longer create widgets.  The single call to `root.mainloop()` at the very end is the only one you need.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper , I really appreciate your contribution. This has fixed my problem. Thank you agian.